# Python one-liner

Tags: python, sum

I want a one-liner solution in Python of the following code, but how?

```
total = 0
for ob in self.oblist:
    total += sum(v.amount for v in ob.anoutherob)
```

It returns the total value. I want it in a one-liner. How can I do it?

Comment: The canonical is *[How can I put multiple statements in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167127/)* (though it was posted later).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There isn't any need to double up on the `sum()` calls:

```
total = sum(v.amount for ob in self.oblist for v in ob.anotherob)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just collapse the `for` loop into another level of comprehension:

```
total = sum(sum(v.amount for v in ob.anotherob) for ob in self.oblist)
```