# Combine list of lists to another list of lists by a certain length in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a one liner to convert

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1], [1], [1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

to

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

where the algorithm combines the lists up to a certain threshold length.

I currently have this

```
batched = []
batch = []
for l in lists:
    batch.extend(l)
    if len(batch) > threshold:
        batched.append(batch)
        batch = []
```

Comment: Where's your attempt? Is it really just lists of 1s in your list? Are you just looking to group by a certain length?

Comment: What if you gets `[ [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1],  [1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1] ]`

Comment: @not_a_robot no I don't have just 1's and yes I do want to group by a certain length

Comment: that could have been a good question.

Comment: What is the question?  You don't seem to have any issues w/ your attempt.

Comment: @ScottHunter I am looking for a *one liner*, its in the first sentence of the question

Comment: I think the question is: what's the one-liner to do that. Considering that there's accumulation and global list length testing, it's not trivial.

Comment: Why does it need to be a one-liner? Its clear from the logic in your current approach that a one liner would be hard to read/maintain

Comment: @Sayse: hard to write in the first place :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I'm sure its doable, but not something worth getting a headache over right before I head home for the day! :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre challenge accepted, though it's already looking ugly

Comment: Is there any grouping logic, though? You say you have lists of other values, too (e.g. `[2, 2]`); how should these be combined? Is it okay to include 1s and 2s together?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being downvoted, it seems fairly common for questions regarding python one liners to be asked, here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508766/python-one-liner

Comment: @not_a_robot Yes I only care about length, even if every individual element in the first list of lists were different I would still want the same *shaped* result

Comment: @not_a_robot Consider `[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5], [6]] -> [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre like me, the OP should really reconsider trying to do this. Not sure I can get over the final step, I can do it fine if I cheat and flatten the list first. If this is Python 2 then perhaps I can get it done with `flatten` but I think that was removed in Python 3.

Comment: @roganjosh I am trying to do it, and have been for about 20 min, I also was able to flatten the list and group it but I figured this was an interesting problem I came about for the community

Comment: `[([1]*total)[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, total, 3)]` was the closest I came (where total is `sum(len(i) for i in input)` but theres a reason this isn't easy to do, and thats because you shouldn't be doing it (it outputs `[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1]]` if you were curious)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so close now, something wonky with the numbering (when I threw a `2` in) `[[[item for sublist in a for item in sublist][x*y] for x in range(1,4)] for y in range(0, (len([item for sublist in a for item in sublist])/3))]`. I thought it might be conflicting variable names but that doesn't seem to have fixed it :(

Comment: Also, @shane - It is being downvoted because it doesn't show any research effort into addressing the actual question (and its also unlikely to be useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all the help, and I learned that a one liner is not be best for this problem as it is ugly and unreadable and probably inefficient. That being said I did come up with this which seems to work from a different slightly cleaner approach.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> l = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8], [9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
>>> t = 3
>>> b = reduce(lambda p, n: p[:-1] + [p[-1] + n] if len(p[-1]) + len(n) <= t or not p[-1] else p + [n], l, [[]])
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with your original implementation but if you insist oneliner here's one ugly option:

```
from itertools import accumulate, chain, groupby

THRESHOLD = 3
l = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1], [1], [1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
res = [[y for x in g for y in x[1]]
       for k, g in groupby(zip(chain([0], accumulate(len(x) for x in l)), l),
                           lambda x: x[0] // THRESHOLD)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

The idea is to generate list of `(item count so far, sublist)` tuples and group them by dividing count by `THRESHOLD`.

```
>>> temp = list(zip(chain([0], accumulate(len(x) for x in l)), l))
>>> temp
[(0, [1]), (1, [1, 1]), (3, [1, 1, 1]), (6, [1]), (7, [1]), (8, [1]), (9, [1, 1, 1, 1])]
>>> groups = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(temp, lambda x: x[0] // THRESHOLD)]
>>> groups
[[(0, [1]), (1, [1, 1])], [(3, [1, 1, 1])], [(6, [1]), (7, [1]), (8, [1])], [(9, [1, 1, 1, 1])]]
>>> [[y for x in g for y in x[1]] for g in groups]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Cracked it but only because I'm stubborn. It's really ugly and inefficient though and maybe there's a cleaner way but, even if there is, it's not worth it.

```
a = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2], [1], [1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]

b = [[[item for sublist in a for item in sublist][x+(y*3)] for x in range(1,4)] for y in range(0, (len([i for j in a for i in j])/3))]
```

EDIT: Because I was testing this in Python 2.7 I missed the fact that division works differently in Python 3. Thanks @nexus66 for pointing out a modification (which just makes it even longer!).

```
c = [[[item for sublist in a for item in sublist][x+(y*3)] for x in range(1,4)] for y in range(0, int((len([i for j in a for i in j])/3)))]
```

Comment: Your code produce an exception. You could update it to `[[[item for sublist in a for item in sublist][x+(y*3)] for x in range(1,4)] for y in range(0, int((len([i for j in a for i in j])/3)))]`

Comment: @nexus66 what exception? I don't get any index error.

Comment: @nexus66 both approaches give me the same answer in 2.7, I wonder if this is Python 3 division?

Comment: It produces this exception `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` within Python3

Comment: Good ansswer, really close to what OP want to have.

Comment: @nexus66 I just realised that the flattening of the list ends up losing the initial structure so the threshold is missed on the final element. That's frustrating.

Comment: True, but still really close to what OP intends to have.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be ideal, but it would be my attempt. The idea is to chain your lists together with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) , then pull from the chain with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and append a new list until you cannot any longer. It admittedly isn't a one liner.

```
from itertools import chain, islice
def grouper(n, li):
    it = chain(*li)
    out_l = []
    while True:
        chunk = list(islice(it, n))
        if len(chunk) < n:
            if chunk:
                out_l[-1] += chunk
            return out_l
        out_l.append(chunk)
```

**Demo**

```
In[238]: orig = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1], [1], [1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
In[239]: grouper(3, orig)
Out[239]: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
In[240]: grouper(4, orig)
Out[240]: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
In[241]: grouper(5, orig)
Out[241]: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
Out[242]: grouper(1, orig)
Out[242]: [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly one-liner... **It's not *exactly* what you asked for** (pretty close), but maybe it'll give you some idea of how to approach it...

```
arr = [[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1], [1], [1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]

threshold = 4

[[x for y in arr for x in y][i:i+threshold] 
     for i, _ in enumerate([x for y in arr for x in y])
       if i % threshold == 0]

Out[31]:
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1]]
```